# Cinema 4D R23.008 Black Viewport

Tags: cinema4d

I downloaded Cinema 4D R23.008 recently and since then it has only shown me a black viewport. What can I do about it?

I have an Intel Core i7, 8gb RAM, and an AMD Radeon HD 7570M laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Laptops with dedicated graphic cards often have another simple graphic chip too. This usually causes problems. Check the manual of your laptop and see if you can disable the chip, so that the Radeon card is doing all the work. You probably have to do this in the BIOS menu.

Additionally, try updating the Radeon driver.

If all this doesn't help, open a support ticket at Maxon.